# Keycloak: How to add cc or bcc while sending email?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-gatekeeper, keycloak-connect

Requirement:

> **How do we add cc or bcc when an email is sent through keycloak?**

Problem:

When a user is invited to sign-up using keycloak invitation mail is sent. But in some cases, the invitation is not sent, so I plan to add cc or bcc to the invitation mail.

Can anyone provide a solution how do i add cc or bcc to keycloak integrated email?

Answer (score 0):

As i checked out 10.0.0v, Keycloak built-in email implementation doesn't contain field for cc or bcc. Eventually, keycloak is open-source. You can write your own [SPIs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#implementing-an-spi) by extending default behaviors. For example;

- Extend [DefaultEmailSenderProvider](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/email/DefaultEmailSenderProvider.java) and add cc & bcc fields java SMTPMessage.
- Extend [FreeMarkerEmailTemplateProvider](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/email/freemarker/FreeMarkerEmailTemplateProvider.java) and override sendVerifyEmail.
- Finally, you need to override **Verify Email** required action and call your SPIs to send